# SQL - Return books that user owns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I'm doing I'm having a bit of a problem performing a query in my university project. I got a website where users share the books that they've read and I have a page where the user can view the books he has added (the books he owns).

For that I believe I need the logged user's id, which I store in a session PHP variable, the user id is in table users.
The information about the books is stored in a table books and it has its own id primary key.
Then, to show who owns what I have a table owns_book (id, u_id, book_id).

Right now for testing I've got 26 books total, 25 of them are added by a user with id of 57 and 1 book by user with id of 49.
When I run this query:

```
SELECT id, title, author, category, cover, added, user_id FROM books, users 
WHERE user_id=49 AND id IN(SELECT book_id FROM owns_book) 
AND user_id IN(SELECT u_id FROM owns_book)
```

And the result is a mess, I don't get the expected one book, I also get books added by the other user.
Can someone please show me the correct query that I need or if I need to change the structure of my tables? Thanks.

EDIT:

```
users(user_id, ...) 
books(id, title, author, publisher, published, cover... ) 
owns_book(id, u_id, book_id)
```

Comment: add the relevant table schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking to to grab everything from your books table that is owned by a specific customer.  If that's the case, you can try

```
SELECT * FROM books 
JOIN owns_book 
ON books.id = owns_books.book_id 
WHERE owns_book.user_id = 49
```

This will select all of the props from your books table then joins the tables based on on the ID of the book being equal to the book_id of the owns_book. Lastly, add the parameter - you only want to see user_id = 49.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this query and use a LEFT JOIN...

```
SELECT books.id, title, author, category, cover, added, users.user_id 
    FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN owns_book on owns_book.user_id = users.user_id
    LEFT JOIN books on books.id = owns_book.id
    WHERE users.user_id=49
```

This links the user_id and lists any books owned by this user_id ( the ON bit of the JOIN).  The WHERE clause just limits to listing records for the user_id your after.

If in the main list of columns, there is a column on multiple tables ( like user_id) then prefix it with the table name to allow the database to detect which column you want to use (even though they may be the same value).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use inner join to join the tables `users` and `books` with the `owns_book` table:

```
SELECT id, title, author, category, cover, added, user_id 
    FROM owns_book 
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = owns_book.u_id
    INNER JOIN books ON books.id = owns_book.book_id
    WHERE users.user_id=49
```